# Installfest ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am a total beginner and I've been doing the installfest at http://railsbridge.org/.

Everything was fine until step 5 of http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_and_deploy_a_rails_app.

Once I type `rails server` in the terminal and click the link, I get the `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError`.

I tried this on both Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8.1. Step 4 had worked when I clicked the link before but now it's giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just type in your terminal:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I've done that but when I do I get on the first line rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /home/jaivon/railsbridge/test_app/db/migrate/20140329014905_create_drinks.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: Please check syntax error in migration file specified in error message  test_app/db/migrate/20140329014905_create_drinks.rb line 5